# calling to ffmpeg executable that the user has installed himself

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to convert an uncompressed .avi to .mp4 from my commercial application.

What i want to do is this:

1. show instructions to the user to download and install ffmpeg to a specific location
2. create and use ffmpeg.exe to compress my .avi to .mp4

Am i allowed (license wise) to do this?

Note: 
I checked https://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html, but it doesn't cover this.

Comment: What do you mean by "create and use ffmpeg.exe"? Many front-ends tell users to download and install a ffmpeg binary themselves. That's not an issue.

Comment: @Gyan Basically, I want to create an .avi - lets say, about 50-60 seconds, uncompressed (probably a good few GB). Then I want to perform compression on it using ffmpeg. Of course, I would use ffmpeg dlls directly if I knew I was allowed to.

Comment: Will you be distributing anything from FFmpeg with your software? Or are you going to leave that up to the user? If the first option, then you don't have to comply with the (L)GPL license of FFmpeg. If the second then you have to comply with the (L)GPL license of FFmpeg.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Got it. In the beginning, it's for sure that I won't redistribute anything from FFmpeg.
In the long term, I may actually use the LGPL license of FFmpeg. If I'm reading the licensing of MPEG LA correctly, it appears that as long as I generate stuff to publish on the internet, less than 12 minutes, I should need to pay nothing if I use the x264 codec